# How do I send dynamic emails based on selections of a Form in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, forms, dynamic, elementor

I have 13 Yes/No questions, and also have 13 answers.

I want to ask those questions in a multi-step form, and based on the user selection, the answers will be sent to them via email.

**Example:** If they said YES to 5 of the questions, then send answers of the 8 questions they said NO to.

If they said YES to all the questions, then no need sending the answers, cos there are no answer to send. Of course, an email will still be sent but the body content won't include any of the answers.

How do I achieve this? I am using Elementor Forms

Comment: Have you looked into the dynamic.ooo plugin? It helped us out in a similar complex form with conditionals and multistep questions.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Actually, dynamic.oo doesn't have such function.